# Naive equivariant transfer

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy

Given a group $G$, a $\mathbb Z$-graded cohomology theory $E^*_G$, and a $n$-sheeted covering $p\colon X \to Y$, I would like a transfer map $$p_!\colon E^*_G X \to E^*_G Y$$ <s>satisfying</s> $$\require{cancel}\xcancel{p_! p^* = n \cdot \mathrm{id}.}$$ [this formulation was wrong; see the comments] such that **when $n$ is inverted, $p_! p^*$ becomes an isomorphism** (what I really need is that $p^*$ is an injection to a direct factor).

I'm aware such transfers exist for arbitrary fibrations $p$ (the number $n$ becomes the Euler characteristic of the fiber) under the additional assumption $E^*_G$ is $RO(G)$-graded, and that the $RO(G)$-grading is necessary for that result, but I only need them for covering maps, and I'd like to avoid the additional hypothesis.

So, are there transfer maps in this generality?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the equivariant cohomology. But, couldn't this be derived from what is known about ordinary homology? For example, doesn't the Becker-Gottlieb together with Atiyah-Hizerbruch-Whitehead SS then gives the result for any cohomology theory?

Comment: I thought that the equation $p_!p^\ast=n$ was false already when $G$ is trivial and $n=2$ (for generalized cohomology theories).

Comment: Well, that would certainly answer my question! What's the example?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie. Trivial $G$ is the non-equivariant case, right? I thought the transfer was implemented by a map $t : \Sigma^\infty_+ Y \to \Sigma^\infty_+ X$ satisfying $t \circ \Sigma^\infty_+ p = 2$. Doesn't that show the desired formula upon applying $Map(-,E)$ for an arbitrary spectrum $E$?

Comment: @OmarAntolinCamarena: the equation is not true, see my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/270996/318

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams. I suppose you mean that in the equivariant case the equation needs higher filtration, right? Although, apart from Theorem 5.5, Becker and Gottlieb state their pull back-push forward formula for any orientable cohomology, which some useful theories do satisfy. The stable (co-) homotopy stable homotopy are very specific examples really! 
What confuses me is that in cohomology or homology, the multiplication by $2$ would imply a splitting away from $2$ taking place in a localised stable homotopy category; how this does match with the higher filtration you mention?

Comment: Thanks, @OscarRandall-Williams, I've believed that false statement for a while now! (Luckily, I've never had to use it.)

Comment: @user51223: I don't mean equivariantly, the equation is false for the ordinary transfer.  The push-pull formula is true for any multiplicative cohomology theory, but shows that $t \circ p$ is multiplication by $t(1) \in \pi^0(Y)$, which is why stable cohomotopy plays a distinguished role. Mapped to ordinary cohomology this is a scalar, namely $\chi(F)$, but that is not generally true. In a general cohomology theory it is $\chi(F)$ modulo higher Atiyah-Hirzebruch filtration, and in particular becomes a unit if $\chi(F)$ is inverted (at least if the base of the fibration is a finite complex).

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams Thank for this. I went back to Brumfiel and Madsen and Madsen-Tillmann to update my knowledge on this. That the equality holds up a filtration, I get it. But, I actually don't know the definition of the Atiyah-Hirzebruch filtration. Is this a filtration on the stable cohomotopy that you refer to or is it related to the fibre bundle that we use and just simply obtained by restriction over the finite subcomplexes of the base of the fibre bundle?

Comment: @user51223, I believe it's the second meant. The filtration $F_p E^*(Y) = \ker(E^* Y \to E^* Y^{p-1})$ gets you $E_2^{p,q} = H^p(Y;E^q(*))$. In the Becker–Gottlieb proof, the additional assumption that $\chi(F)$ is invertible makes $p_! p^*\colon E^* Y \to E^* Y$ induce an automorphism of this $E_2$ page, so that $p_! p^*$ is an automorphism.

Comment: If you ask for a structured enough version of these transfers, and G is finite, then I think this is equivalent to asking for an RO(G)-graded cohomology theory (basically by the equivariant version of Segal's machine.) If you drop down the structure, there might be counterexamples akin to the classical counterexamples of the "transfer conjecture" in nonequivariant homotopy theory. Basically, it's like measuring the difference between an H_infty-space and an E_infty space... there are examples of the former which aren't the latter, but they tend to be weird. In your case, it's like you have

Comment: an E_infty G-space and you want to give it a "G-H_infty" structure without requiring that it be "G-E_infty". This is a little different than the classical transfer story (which begins with just an arbitrary H_infty space and asks whether it's also E_infty) since you do have non-equivariant coherent multiplication. But I think I would still be a little surprised if it turned out that coherent addition + H_infty-style-transfers = coherent transfers.

Comment: So what I'm saying is: it's probably the case that what you're asking for is weaker than having an RO(G)-graded cohomology theory, but actual examples of non-RO(G)-graded-coh-theories which have these transfers would probably be artificially built and not naturally occurring.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So it seems I should just include $RO(G)$-grading as a hypothesis. That said, just in case, all I truly want is the maximum generality under which a covering action of a finite cyclic group $C$ on a $G$-space $X$ (so the actions commute) induces an isomorphism $E^*_G (X/C) \to E^*_G (X)^C$.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to turn my comments into something like an answer (but the 'tldr' version is "I don't know.")

1. When $G=*$, a space $X$ represents a functor with *homotopy coherent* transfers if and only if $X$ is a $\Gamma$-space (and hence equivalent to an $E_{\infty}$-space). Actually, you might take 'being a $\Gamma$-space' as the *definition* of having homotopy coherent transfers. One could (and Quillen did) ask whether this is equivalent to just asking that $[-,X]$ has functorial transfers for finite covers. That was called "the transfer conjecture". This turns out to be the same as asking that $X$ be an $H_{\infty}$-space. And so one asks "Is every $H_{\infty}$-space an $E_{\infty}$-space?" The answer is no, and a counterexample was provided by Kraines and Lada.
2. For finite $G$, a $G$-space $X$ represents a functor with homotopy coherent transfers for finite covers (of $G$-spaces) if and only if it admits the structure of an equivariant Segal space (and hence is equivalence to a $G-E_{\infty}$-space. So, up to group completion, $X$ is the zeroth space of a genuine $G$-spectrum (and so represents an $RO(G)$-graded cohomology theory).
3. If $X$ is a $G$-space representing a functor with homotopy coherent transfers for finite covers *fibered in trivial $G$-sets*, then this is like saying $X$ is an $E_{\infty}$-space in $G$-spaces. In particular, up to group completion, it admits ordinary deloopings and represents a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded cohomology theory for $G$-spaces.
4. In your situation, you seem to have a space $X$ as in (3) and are asking if it's possibly to ask that $[-,X]$ admit transfers for all covers without requiring that $X$ admit $RO(G)$-deloopings, i.e. without requiring that $X$ be equivalent to a $G-E_{\infty}$-space. My guess is that this *is* possible, but that any example would be manufactured (like the counterexample of Kraines and Lada). However, I should point out that this situation is not precisely parallel to that in (1) because you have *already* placed an $E_{\infty}$-structure on $X$, so it's at least plausible that this homotopy coherence together with some weak notion of more exotic transfers could be enough... but again, I doubt it.
5. In your last comment you mention that you are only interested in transfers for covers with cyclic structure group. Even for those, I think I stand by my intuition from (4), but I could be wrong. One imagines that whatever obstruction is responsible for establishing the conjectured example in (4) would be known to cyclic covers, especially after localizing at a prime.
6. I've gone this whole answer without saying $N_{\infty}$-operad. Consider it said. (It's relevant to this business of asking for fewer transfers, somewhere between "fibered in trivial $G$-sets" and "fibered in arbitrary $G$-sets". Blumberg-Hill is the place to learn about these.)